# Why BLE device is disconnecting after one day in API level 26+?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working with BLE device which is sending data in every seconds. I recently changed target Version to 28 and found that the Bluetooth service/ BLE device get disconnected after 1 day in samsung J7 and 4 days in pixel device. We need the service must be connected at least for 3 days. Wondering how to fix this issue.

any suggestion is acceptable.

Comment: Check this solutions Click Here[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49364419/android-ble-handling-disconnect-timeout)

Comment: this doesn't solve my problem